# Query Custom Post by Taxonomy Category

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i hope you are well today,

My question is just breif i am trying to query from a custom post type by a certain taxonomy only;

to keep it streamline lets use the below as an example;

**Custom Post Type:** *'Products';*

**Taxonomy:** *'Categories';*

**Categories within 'Categories';**

*(1) Category 1
(2) Category 2
(3) Category 3*

So i would like query posts from the Custom Post Type **'Products'** and within **'Category 1'**

How would this be done ?

Here is my code for what querying the custom post type and attempting to query the taxonomy category.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $post_per_page = -1; // -1 shows all posts
    $do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
    $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'taxonomy' => 'category-1',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    $temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( have_posts() ) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 3 ways of doing that:

a)

```
...
'category_name' => 'category-1'
...
```

b)

```
...

'taxonomy' => 'category',
'term' => 'category-1',

...
```

c)

```
...
'tax_query' => array(
  array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => array( 'category-1' ) )
)
...
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 2):

tax_query array with taxonomy, field and terms. Where terms->business is the category of taxonomy-> job_category

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'featured_job',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 9999999,
    'orderby' =>  'date',
    'order' => 'DES',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  'business',
        ),
    ),
);
```